# Returning a value based on multiple criteria and ranges of numbers

Tags: excel

> I am looking for a way to do some type of lookup/match to come up
>   with bonuses. It is based on what they sold, for how much, and based on how much they sold last year, and the amount increased.
>
> Example Line 2: So say they sold $900 worth of pens to Joe (New Amount is w/in 1-999). Last 
>   year Joe only bought $23 worth of pens (Previous Amount is w/in 1-24) they get a $25 bonus (Bonus). Also..
>
> There also has to be a minimum increase amount (Min increase column). So say if Joe bought
>   $999 worth of pens last year and $1000 worth of pens this year, the
>   salesperson shouldn't get a bonus because it was only a buck increase. It has to be at least $50 increase in this case. That's what the Min Increase column is.

```
Group   Min Increase    Previous Amount     New Amount      Bonus
                        Min Max             Min     Max 
Pens    50              1   24              1000    999999  45
Pens    50              1   24              1        999    25
Pens    50              25  100             1000    999999  45
Pens    5               25  100             1        999    25
Paper   10              1   24              1000    999999  50
Paper   10              1   24              1        999    25
Paper   10              25  100             1000    999999  50
Paper   5               25  100             1        999    25
```

I started looking at Indexmatching but it's not enough. Then I thought of summing, but it's really not adding anything together.

=SUMIFS(B3:B10, G1:G10, "Pens", D3:D10, "50")

Also, =INDEX(range2,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(range1,range2)>0,0)) won't work because that's only two ranges.

It also has to be something they can update constantly.

The actual data looks something like this

```
Sale   Prev. Group
900    23    Pens
```

So you'd need to find the difference, see if it's within the minimum increase for the group and the amounts (900-23 > 50).  Then return a value.  23 is between 1 and 24 and 900 is between 1 and 999 so $25 bonus.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm looking into index matching, but I can't find out how to do it with ranges.

Thanks

Comment: how do you distinguish the different pen groups? some are 50 some are 5 for min increase.  Currently I find the Min Max confusing at the do not seem to tie into your written example.

Comment: It is confusing. There are 4 pen groups. The first two the previous sale was 1-24. The second group the previous sale was 25-100.  Then, the new sale is either 1-999 or 1000 and up. I realize it doesn't cover every situation and make logical sense (sometimes it doesn't in our real life examples, either!). I was trying to keep it simple and just cover a variety of situations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: POC]

The formula is based on aggregate which performs array like operations.  As such keep full column references inside of the aggregate function as short as you can and avoid full column references.  Based on the layout of information in the picture above, place the following formula in L3 and copy down as required.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$10)/(($A$3:$A$10=$K3)*($C$3:$C$10<=$J3)*($D$3:$D$10>=$J3)*($E$3:$E$10<=$I3)*($F$3:$F$10>=$I3)*((I3-J3)>=$B$3:$B$10)),1)),"No Bonus")
```

Caveat:  If for some reason, the sales situation matches multiple rows in your table, then it will return the bonus corresponding to the lowest row number that met all the criteria.

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect. I would have never come up with that on my own.  I appreciate it!